# NSolve does not work

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve this eq'

$$((1 - t) r)/(1 - x) = \log[\exp[(r t )/x] + 1 - \exp[r]$$

without success, I tried to get a specific numeric solution

```
NSolve[-(0.25/(1 - x)) == Log[1. + 0.606531 (-0.5 + x)], {x}]
```

The output is the same line I wrote

Comment: NSolve[-(0.25/(1 - x)) == Log[1. + 0.606531 (-0.5 + x)], {x}, Reals]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSolve[-0.25/(1 - x) == Log[1. + 0.606531 (-0.5 + x)], x, Reals]
```

(*

{{x -> 0.100092}, {x -> 1.51936}}

*)

[image]

Even

```
Solve[-0.25/(1. - x) == Log[1. + 0.606531 (-0.5 + x)], x, Reals]
```

works.

Answer (score 1):

For the transcendental equations `FindRoot` is a better choice.

```
FindRoot[-(0.25/(1 - x)) == Log[1. + 0.606531 (-0.5 + x)], {x, 1.5}]

(* {x -> 1.51936}  *)

FindRoot[-(0.25/(1 - x)) == Log[1. + 0.606531 (-0.5 + x)], {x, 0.5}]

(*  {x -> 0.100092}  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: *Why* is `FindRoot` "a better choice" than `NSolve` or `Solve`?

Comment: And how did you know to seed the solutions at 1.5 and at .5?

Comment: @ David G. Stork If a transcendental equation has an exact solution `Solve` is the best choice, that's evident. If not, one can either use `NSolve` or `FindRoot`. I remember that years ago there was a discussion on this and the general opinion was that in this case, `FindRoot` is better. I, however, never tried to find out why is it so.

Comment: @David G. Stork  To address your second question. I know it from the plot published in your answer. I did not discuss it, since it is rather evident.